# Regex: optional group

Tags: regex

I want to split a string like this:

```
abc//def//ghi
```

into a part before and after the first occurrence of `//`:

```
a: abc
b: //def//ghi
```

I'm currently using this regex:

```
(?<a>.*?)(?<b>//.*)
```

Which works fine so far.

However, sometimes the `//` is missing in the source string and obviously the regex fails to match. How is it possible to make the second group optional?

An input like `abc` should be matched to:

```
a: abc
b: (empty)
```

I tried `(?<a>.*?)(?<b>//.*)?` but that left me with lots of NULL results in Expresso so I guess it's the wrong idea.

Comment: are you sure that you **need** regexp?

Comment: Regex does this fine, no reason not to use it.

Comment: Regex is never `needed`. In this case I like to use regex because the above is just a simplified part of something bigger that _needs_ regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try a ^ at the begining of your expression to match the begining of the string and a $ at the end to match the end of the string (this will make the ungreedy match work).

```
^(?<a>.*?)(?<b>//.*)?$
```

Comment: Obviously the second expression in the question (the one with the trailing ? after the second group).

Comment: I get a single NULL result when I try this.

Comment: @mafutrct - I hadn't run it through expresso so hadn't noticed the ungreedy match, added a $ to fix it. Works correctly now.

Comment: Great! Thanks to Kamarey as well, who just deleted his correct answer.

Comment: `^(?<a>.*?)(?://(?<b>.*))?$` would probably be better. No need to capture `//` .

Comment: @Brad Gilbert - That was an expression I considered suggesting, but the example text at the top of the question has multiple // instances. So I left the // in the second group for consistancys sake.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but why is it that the ungreedy match works only after adding the `$` at the end? I have a similar structure and when I make group `a` greedy, i.e. `(?<a>.*)`, it matches the whole string and the optional group will never be matched (even when it is present). However, when I make group `a` ungreedy, the regex matches nothing. See: https://regex101.com/r/TSqFUC/1. Check the two options by adding a `?` in group `a`. However when `$` is added, the regex does work in the ungreedy variant.

Comment: @tobyvd by adding the `$` to the end of the regex you're forcing the greedy group to allow the next group(s) to match characters that it could also match as the whole regex needs to get to the end of the string.

Comment: @stevehipwell but how come in the ungreedy variant for group `a`, it wouldn't match the optional group? What I see, is that the `$` forces the regex to make a match to the end of the line, and then with backtracking figure out that the optional group is present before giving the remainder to the ungreedy group. I think what I don't understand is why the ungreedy+optional group rather matches nothing instead of detecting and matching the optional group that is present.

Comment: @tobyvd a greedy pattern earlier in the regex has precedence over an optional pattern later in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

A proof of Stevo3000's answer (Python):

```
import re

test_strings = ['abc//def//ghi', 'abc//def', 'abc']

regex = re.compile("(?P<a>.*?)(?P<b>//.*)?$")

for ts in test_strings:
    match = regex.match(ts)
    print 'a:', match.group('a'), 'b:', match.group('b')

a: abc b: //def//ghi
a: abc b: //def
a: abc b: None
```

Answer (score -1):

Why use group matching at all? Why not just split by `"//"`, either as a regex or a plain string?

```
use strict;

my $str = 'abc//def//ghi';
my $short = 'abc';

print "The first:\n";
my @groups = split(/\/\//, $str, 2);
foreach my $val (@groups) {
print "$val\n";
}

print "The second:\n";
@groups = split(/\/\//, $short, 2);
foreach my $val (@groups) {
print "$val\n";
}
```

gives

```
The first:
abc
def//ghi
The second:
abc
```

[EDIT: Fixed to return max 2 groups]

Comment: All // after the first // are to be ignored.

Comment: I didn't catch that.
I still think my solution is the easiest to understand, use the limit parameter present in most split functions.